# Archive file with date-stamp

Tags: shell, backup

I want to move(archive) the multiple files from say directory `/users/wahasan` to `/users/wahasan/old`. The archive files should be autodated.

files are of the format `CHKBOI.pos`, `CHKUTI.pos`, `CHKSBI.pos`,so on. here `CHK` and `.pos` are common in every file name.

I need a single shell script that should move all the files from source directory to destination with date-stamp.

Comment: And the date is the date of creation? today? date of last modification? Have you tried something?

Comment: Hi waseem hasan. Please **[edit]** your question to add some details on what you have tried, what the results were, how those results differed from what you want, and as specifically as possible **what you need to know in order to proceed.** At the time it is hard to tell exactly what you are asking for. Note that the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is not a script writing service; we aim to help people coming across these questions in the future as well, potentially years from now, which means that we prefer questions which are likely to help future visitors as well as the original asker.

Comment: Yes fredtantini. If i move the file today, then file should be appended with today's date. i am a beginner in Unix shell Scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Pure BASH version:

```
dir='/users/wahasan';stamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S); for file in $dir/CHK*.pos; do nn=${file/CHK/old/CHK}; nn=${nn/pos/pos_$stamp}; echo "$file  --->  $nn";mv $file $nn; done
```

try it, should work

ED:

```
dir='/users/wahasan';          ## path to work directory
stamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S);  ## date_time stamp
for file in $dir/CHK*.pos; do  ## getting list of all files to be moved
    nn=${file/CHK/old/CHK};    ## generating new absolute path [1] (adding '/old/')
    nn=${nn/pos/pos_$stamp};   ## generating new absolute path [2] (adding stamp)
    echo "$file  --->  $nn";   ## showing what will be moved to what (can be removed)
    mv $file $nn;              ## moving
done
```

Comment: Thanks Netikras, i used the below script and it worked fine:                                                        #!/bin/sh
TODAYS_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`; export TODAYS_DATE
for file in `ls /u001/users/autosys/wahasan/CHKNB*.pos`
#while [ "$file" != "CHKNB*.POS" ]
do
  mv $file /u001/users/autosys/wahasan/old/`basename $file`.$TODAYS_DATE
done